# Iterate Through Row Major-Stored Array in Column Major Order

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on a multi-dimensional array class (leaving out the complex/irrelevant details). I am storing the data as a linear array stored in row major order. I need to create an iterator that can iterate over the array in column-major order. Given that the data is stored in row major order, the row major iterator can simply increment the index into the array. However, I'm not sure how to go about implementing the column major iterator. I'm guessing there's a formula I can use to calculate the index but have not been able to locate it anywhere or derive it myself. Rearranging the data is not an option, as regardless i need both iterators.

Comment: `i = n; i < length; i += row_length`

Comment: Neither of those iterates through the array, just a subset of its elements.

Comment: Yes that would only iterate through a subset. I do have the dimensions of the array available to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
last_idx = width * height - 1;

if(pos == last_idx)
{
    end;
}
else {
    pos += width;
    if(pos > last_idx) pos -= last_idx;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that it's a 2D array, doesn't it? How would you do it for a higher-dimension array?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example
const int ROWS = 4;
const int COLS = 5;

// Initial
int row = 0;
int col = 0;

// Iteration
row += 1;
col += row / ROWS;
row %= ROWS;

// Index into your array
row * ROWS + col

// Termination
row * ROWS + col < ROWS * COLS
```

Comment: This does -- I really only used const to indicate the dimensions aren't changing while iterating -- which would inevitably break any iteration.

Comment: What I meant is that, for example, it would need to work with a 2x3x4x5 array. So there could be more than just rows and columns.

Comment: The idea is still the same, just increment row and col conditionally on a full iteration of the 3rd dimension, etc. etc.  You can use the same `mod` `/` trick on the inner dimensions.

Comment: @AnthonySottile, it's not clear what you mean by "just increment row and col conditionally on a full iteration of the 3rd dimension, etc. etc." Could you somehow work that into the code? Also, what if you don't know the number of dimensions at the time the code is written? What if you just know that there will be a vector that contains the dimensions of the array?

Comment: if your dimensions were `(3, 4, 5)` you'd mod/div by `5` for the inner rows, mod/div by `4 * 5` for the next set of rows, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Given dimensions of array you can create mapping table and have iterator iterate over it.

```
array[mapping_table[i]]
```

Comment: And how would you create the mapping table? What would it look like? If you give an example, please make sure it's not specific to a 2D array.